# Route different tasks to different Queues

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery with RabbitMQ as broker.

The code that creates Celery app instance is

```
from celery import Celery

name = __file__.split('.')[0]

app = Celery(name)
app.config_from_object('celery_config')


@app.task
def fetch_url(url):
  resp = requests.get(url)
  print resp.status_code

@app.task
def post(url, **kwargs):
  body = kwargs.get(payload)
  auth = kwrags.get(auth)
  resp = requests.put(url, data=body, auth=auth)
```

Now I want to have 2 separate Queues, one for GET and one for POST.

Now I know that I must define the 2 queues in celery config module like

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('get', Exchange('get')),
    Queue('post', Exchange('post')),
)
```

What I don't get is exactly what string to specify for the 'routing_key' option? Should it be the name of the tasks(get & post in this case) or there are rules for defining the routing_key?

Answer (score 0):

No need to define queues or deal with routing keys, bindings or exchanges for simple task routing as your case. This is much simplified now (version 4.1) using the automatic routing.(http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing)

1. Name your tasks. For example, lets say you give names as below.

`@app.task(name='get_task')
 def fetch_url(url):`

`@app.task(name='post_task')
 def post(url):`

2. Add below line in your celery config file to route tasks to proper queues.

`task_routes = {
'get_task': {'queue': 'get_queue'},
'post_task': {'queue': 'post_queue'}
}`

Since task_create_missing_queues config is enabled by default, celery will take care of creating the queues for you.